# Push Notification on iOS with Azure Notification Hub and documentation

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification, maui, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to add push notifications in my .NET 8 MAUI application. I was looking at the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/remote-notifications-in-ios) and the function
`public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications` is probably what I need. In the app, I'm calling via `HttpClient` the Azure Notification Hub` to register the device. In the documentation, Microsoft overrides this function:

```cs
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (
UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    // Get current device token
    var DeviceToken = deviceToken.Description;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DeviceToken)) {
        DeviceToken = DeviceToken.Trim('<').Trim('>');
    }

    // Get previous device token
    var oldDeviceToken = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("PushDeviceToken");

    // Has the token changed?
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldDeviceToken) || !oldDeviceToken.Equals(DeviceToken))
    {
        // TODO: Put your own logic here to notify your server that 
        // the device token has changed/been created!
    }

    // Save new device token
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(DeviceToken, "PushDeviceToken");
}
```

In the documentation, it is clear that I can have a `DeviceToken` and then add my custom code to register the device in the Azure Notification Hub. Unfortunately, this override doesn't exist in the `AppDelegate` in the `iOS` project.

Where is this function coming from? How can I register my iOS device using `HttpClient` and then receive the notification?

### Update

It says `no suitable method found to override`.

[image]

This is contained in

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate, 
IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// ...

public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, 
      NSData deviceToken)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking. The `RegisteredForRemoteNotifications` is not there by default, but you can add it, as it's shown above, and it will work.

Comment: I tried but it is not working. Maybe, I missed something. I have just updated the post.

Comment: I tried the `Shiny` framework. If I use the `Azure` implementation, the application returns an error because the token is `null`. Because the project wasn't built, I created my repo with the project _Sample.Maui.Push_ fixed but the token is still `null` https://github.com/erossini/MauiShiny

Comment: Finally, I found the solution and I [wrote a post](https://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/maui/maui-push-notifications-using-azure-notification-hub-for-ios/) to explain all the steps to send and receive push notification from Azure Notification Hub in iOS